# Значение корней в словах

Tags: корень-слова, сложные-прилагательные

В каком из сложных слов корни соотносятся друг с другом по смыслу не так, как в остальных?
*Бронебойный, плодоносный, мышевидный, травоядный, потогонный.*

Comment: мышевидный-похожий на мышь, а остальные образованы от переходных глаголов (бить броню, носить плоды, есть траву, гнать пот)

Comment: @Людмила. Этот вопрос похож на д/з, поэтому не стоило отвечать. Но раз уж Вы ответили, то почему только в виде комментария? Теперь система будет бесконечно возвращать этот вопрос как неотвеченный.

Answer (score 1):

**брон/е/бо́й/н/ый**
**плод/о/но́с/н/ый**
**мыш/е/ви́д/н/ый**
**трав/о/я́д/н/ый**
**пот/о/го́н/н/ый**

Бронебойный, плодоносный, травоядный, потогонный — неодушевлённое существительное + глагол.
Мышевидный — одушевлённое существительное (мышь) + неодушевлённое существительное (вид). Не *видеть* мышь, а иметь *вид мыши*, быть похожим на мышь.

Например: змеевидный, стекловидный, кольцевидный, колосовидный, грушевидный.